# Write image with more than 256 labels

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have a 2-D labelled matrix that comes from `bwlabel`, but it could have labels with indices greater than 4000. It is simple to show via `imshow` with more than 256 colours:

```
img = zeros(1000, 1000);
%Put 4000 seeds
for numCentroid = 1:4000
    x = randi([1 size(img, 1)]);
    y = randi([1 size(img, 2)]);
    img(x, y) = 1;
end
D = bwdist(img);
% Create the 'cell' regions
L_img = watershed(D); % We obtain a labelled image
imshow(L_img, repmat(colorcube(256), 20, 1));
```

However, when we do the same, but with `imwrite`:

```
imwrite(L_img, repmat(colorcube(256), 20, 1), 'p.tif');
```

And obtain this error:

> Error using wtifc 
>   Invalid colormap for 8 bit image, must have dimensions n X 3 (n<=256).

It is also reproducible with other formats such as png:

```
 imwrite(uint16(randi([0 4000], 200)), colorcube(4001), 'p.png')
```

> Error using writepng (line 76) 
>  
>   Invalid bitdepth for indexed image; must be 1, 2, 4, or 8.

Here's an example of the image we want to save:

[image: image to write]

What we want is to obtain an indexed image with each separated region labelled.  How can we save this image?

Since we know it is a problem of the `imwrite` itself because it transforms the double matrix into `uint8`, we tried to put the same matrix as `uint16`. This is not working either.

Edit 1:

Showing the bit depth of the image in Matlab is the correct 16 bits.

```
imfinfo('p.tif')
```

However, if you check the same thing, but in Windows: `right click on the file -> Properties -> Details`, it has 8-bit depth. This correlates with:

```
help imwrite
```

> **Allowed Values for BitDepth of TIFF files** 
>  Grayscale images: 1, 2, 4, 8, or 16 
>  
>   Grayscale images with an alpha channel: 8 or 16 
>  
>   Indexed images: 1, 2, 4, or 8 
>   Truecolor images: 8 or 16

Comment: What image formats can you use? Is .tiff or .png required?

Comment: Do you really to write the _indexed_ image? It seems to work if you first convert it to an RGB image: `x = uint16(randi([0 4000], 200)); cmap = colorcube(4001); cmap1 = cmap(:,1); cmap2 = cmap(:,2); cmap3 = cmap(:,3); x_rgb = cat(3, cmap1(x+1), cmap2(x+1), cmap3(x+1)); imwrite(x_rgb, 'p.png')`

Comment: @gnovice No, any usual format without loss of information

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks, it does export it correctly, but when you open the image it is an RGB file, not an indexed image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Adriaan pointed out in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52519604/7328782), you can write 16-bit TIFF files. If the file needs to be indexed (i.e. have a separate color map), and have 16-bit indices, then TIFF is the only standard file format I know of that will do the job.

Given the 16-bit index image, and a 4001-element color map:

```
data = uint16(randi([0 4000], 200));
cm = colorcube(4001);
```

then:

```
imwrite(data,cm,'p.tif')
```

will write this correctly to file:

```
cris@paella> tiffinfo p.tif 
TIFF Directory at offset 0x13ba0 (80800)
  Image Width: 200 Image Length: 200
  Resolution: 72, 72 pixels/inch
  Bits/Sample: 16
  Compression Scheme: PackBits
  Photometric Interpretation: palette color (RGB from colormap)
  Orientation: row 0 top, col 0 lhs
  Samples/Pixel: 1
  Rows/Strip: 40
  Planar Configuration: single image plane
  Color Map: (present)
```

(`tiffinfo` is a program that comes with LibTIFF, and is often installed by default on Unix distros, I have installed LibTIFF on my Mac using Homebrew).

Note the "Bits/Sample: 16" line, and "Photometric Interpretation: palette color (RGB from colormap)". This TIFF file now has a color map with 65536 entries.

We can read the file back too:

```
[data2,cm2] = imread('p.tif');
```

`isequal(data,data2)` returns `true`, and `class(data2)` returns `'uint16'`. `cm2` is not the same as `cm`, as it contains many more entries (which are all 0). But `cm2(1:4001,:)` and `cm` are nearly identical, the differences come from `cm` being floating-point values, which were multiplied by 65535 and rounded for saving to the file.

The problem, as I expressed in comments underneath Adriaan's answer, is that most software will not read 16-bit indexed TIFF files. For example, Photoshop Elements will not open the `p.tif` file we created here, nor will Apple's Preview program. The reason is that Baseline TIFF (the lowest-common denominator standard that all TIFF readers must comply with) specifies only 4-bit and 8-bit indexed images. 16-bit indexed images is an extension.

Thus, if you want to save a 16-bit indexed image, first make sure that the target software will be able to read it.

Comment: Thank you. So, do you know any program that can read 16-bit indexed images?

Comment: @Pablo: Well, MATLAB reads the file correctly... What do you want to do with the image? What is the ultimate goal? Photo software tends to focus on photographs, which have an RGB triplet per pixel. Indexed images were, in the old days, a way to save on memory, but that has become somewhat irrelevant nowadays. So indexed images have become somewhat of a niche, not so important to support.

Comment: Yes, we have the resulting labelled images in Matlab, but, sometimes, we need to manually curate them. Therefore, we require to modify these images outside Matlab (Photoshop, for instance). An indexed image is very helpful because we can export the image, change the index of a region that is wrong, and return it modified in Matlab. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Pablo: Do you then need the color map also? Can you do that without the color map? 16-bit grey-value image’s *should* be no problem in Photoshop, though I don’t know if you can select colors to draw with that are outside the 0-255 range.

Comment: @Pablo: Also, do you realize that, if `img` is your image with 4000+ labels, you can do `img(img==105)=108` to change the region with label 105 to be 108? It might be easier to do the whole thing in MATLAB.

Comment: 1.- If I'd do that you don't preserve the index and I cannot know the correspondence between two different images.
2.- I don't intend to change all the cells, but pixels that are usually 0 (not corresponding with any cell). We have to change small regions that can't be fixed with simple morphological operations (erode, dilate, area open, ...). Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Sorry, I though you wanted to be able to "change the index of a region that is wrong". I was suggesting you do this in MATLAB, instead of Photoshop or similar. Other interaction can be built in MATLAB too, but it's a bit of effort.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation, inputting a `uint16` file writes a `uint16` file, provided the file format supports that:

> If `A` is of data type uint16 and the output file format supports 16-bit data (JPEG, PNG, and TIFF), then `imwrite` outputs 16-bit values. If the output file format does not support 16-bit data, then `imwrite` returns an error.

From the [documentation on `imwrite`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html)

```
img = rand(1e3);
L_img = bwlabel(img);
imshow(L_img, repmat(colorcube(256), 20, 1));
Warning: Image is too big to fit on screen; displaying at 67% 
> In images.internal.initSize (line 71)
  In imshow (line 305) 

imwrite(L_img, repmat(colorcube(256), 20, 1), 'p.tif');
Error using wtifc
Invalid colormap for 8 bit image, must have dimensions n X 3 (n<=256).

Error in writetif (line 118)
wtifc(data, map, filename, writemode, colorspace, required_tags);

Error in imwrite (line 472)
        feval(fmt_s.write, data, map, filename, paramPairs{:});

tmp = uint16(L_img);
imwrite(tmp, repmat(colorcube(256), 20, 1), 'p.tif'); %Writes the file to my disk
```

Comment: Thanks. Have you tried to open 'p.tif'? We can't open it, not even with Photoshop.

Comment: @PabloVicenteMunuera does saving as `.tiff` help? I don't have any fancy image tools installed, but MATLAB seems to be able to open the files (i.e. read to a `cdata` and `colormap` variable) with ease.

Comment: Nope. Yes, we are aware of what you said about `cdata` and `colormap`. But we need to open that file externally, so we have to preserve the labels of each cell as an indexed image. Thanks anyway.

Comment: A lot of software doesn’t support TIFF files other than 8-bit unsigned integers. It’s a shame because TIFFs can contain many more pixel types.

Comment: @CrisLuengo We don't care about the format, it is also happening with .png format.

Comment: @Pablo: but this is an issue with Photoshop not being able to open the file, not with MATLAB not being able to write it. If you need a file with 4000 indices, you need to write a 16-bit type. Photoshop won’t be able to read that.

Comment: @Pablo That's the thing, it is not: Photoshop can read 16-bit images. However, we can't export an image of more than 8-bit labels using `imwrite` in Matlab, without losing the label of each cell.

Comment: @Pablo: But Adriaan showed how to write such a file, and he can read it back in MATLAB. You said Photoshop can’t open that file.

Comment: @CrisLuengo You can't open with any program to visualize it or modify it. So, you are not exporting correctly the image

Comment: Most of the image format simply do not support more than 256 indexed color.

Comment: @obchardon: TIFF actually does support 16-bit indices and 65k element color tables. If it has to contain a color table, TIFF is the only approach I know of.

Comment: I realized if you see the properties of the exported image 'p.tif', the bit depth is still 8 bits, not 16. It is not corresponding with the exported 16-bit image, isn't it?